# Getting variable size in C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

i have an problem, i am writing a header file, which depending on the Sizes of the c standard datatypes, defines different Structs and Unions. I would need something like this:

```
#if sizeof(int) == 4
    typedef struct {
        int i;
    } test;
#else
    typedef struct {
        long i;
    } test;
#endif
```

sadly this doesnt work.

Does somebody know, how i can do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `#if INT_MAX == 2147483647` ... remember to `#include <limits.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do it this way as preprocessor does not know anything about the C language, but for this purpose you have fixed size integer types which are standard and portable

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t i;
} test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you can't. What you can do however is take "well known" preprocessor definitions as hints to decide which architecture, compiler and OS you're targeting and decide from that.